# Google play publish issue

Tags: google-play

I getting this error and i cannot resolve the problem, i changed my all images but i still getting this error message

> Your app submission has been rejected for a violation of the Google
>   Play Developer Program Policy regarding Intellectual Property. If this
>   submission was an update to an existing app, the version published
>   prior to this update is still available in Google Play. Please review
>   the copyright infringement and impersonation help articles, then
>   remove unlicensed images from your app and/or listing and
>   resubmit.Additional details have been sent to your account owner's
>   email address.

Comment: Please advise :'( , i changed all icons, titles, images, but my application reject Immediately after renew

Comment: Did u found why Google team sent this mail? I too got this mail.

Comment: Yes, i had some images from some Hollywood actors in my app